# linux unable to connect to XDebug on port 9000

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

I'm currently trying to get Netbeans as an IDE to work with PHP Files. Part of the work is to get Xdebug to run properly. I have gotten Xdebug to work on a Windows machine but this is my first try on Linux.

I have gotten the correct module I followed the instructions on http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

I have a Correct phpinfo() output also, with the Xdebugsection pressent and everything. I can't post the output of my phpinfo() but everything seems ok there. The configuration in my php.ini file is as follows:

```
 [XDebug]
 zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/xdebug.so"
 xdebug.remote_enable=on
 xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
 xdebug.remote_mode=req
 xdebug.remote_host=localhost
 xdebug.remote_port=9101


 [ZendModules]
 Xdebug
```

I only want to be able to connect to the port 9101 (The port Xdebug listens on). I have gotten the following small script from a website to do so.

```
 <?php
 $address = '127.0.0.1';
 $port = 9101;
 print $port . " " .$address . "\n";
 $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
 print "sock = " . $sock . "\n";
 socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Unable to bind');
 print "socket bind worked \n";
 socket_listen($sock);
 print "listening on sock\n";
 $client = socket_accept($sock);
 echo "connection established: $client";
 socket_close($client);
 socket_close($sock);
 ?>
```

When I run this script, I get the following output:

```
michael@michael-Inspiron-N5030:~$ php5 testXdebug.php 
9101 127.0.0.1
sock = Resource id #4
socket bind worked 
listening on sock
```

This means the Script will not finish running, it just stops there an nothing else happens.

does somebody have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: The problem waqs, that I was not creating a request to the webserver. The PHP script will only terminate if something builds up a connection to port 9101 and I was not doing this since XDebug will only establish this connection once a PHP file is called on the webserver.